# Oracle SQL - display values up to current record

Tags: sql, oracle

Can I use LISTAGG or a similar analytical function in Oracle SQL to display all values in group up to current record?

This is my table:

```
id      group_id   value
--      --------   -----
1       1          A
2       1          B
3       1          C
4       2          X
5       2          Y
6       2          Z
```

I would like the following result:

```
id      group_id   values
--      --------   ------
1       1          A
2       1          AB
3       1          ABC
4       2          X
5       2          XY
6       2          XYZ
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option, using a correlated subquery to handle the rollup of the `value` column:

```
SELECT
    t1.id,
    t1.group_id,
    (SELECT LISTAGG(t2.val, '') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY t2.id)
     FROM yourTable t2
     WHERE t1.group_id = t2.group_id AND t2.id <= t1.id) AS vals
FROM yourTable t1
ORDER BY
    t1.id;
```

### Demo

The logic here is that, for each group, with rollup a concatenation of all values coming at or before the current `id` value in a given row.

Another approach to this, one which might perform and scale better, would be to use a recursive CTE.  But, that would take more code, and might be harder to digest than what I wrote above.

Comment: You should note that `listagg(value, '') within group (order by id) over (partition by group_id order by id)` is not permitted, because Oracle doesn't support the cumulative `listagg()` analytic function (although `listagg()` can be used as a non-cumulative analytic function).